# SELECT/INSERT performance on an indexed column while it's being updated in MYSQL InnoDB

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

Let's say i have a table with structure like this:

```
id (int[11]), name(VARCHAR[255])
```

`name` column has a b-tree index.

And let's assume that there were queries to this table in this order:

1. INSERT
2. SELECT
3. INSERT

Now, I know that when inserting a new row in an indexed table the index needs to be updated. This takes time. But **my questions are**:

1. Would SELECT wait for index to be updated or just search the previous version of table or is there something else to this?
2. What would happen to the second INSERT? Would it wait for index to be fully updated from previous INSERT or not?

Thank you.

> UPDATE

Assume that insert haven't finished updating the index by the time SELECT query is issued.

Comment: Its totally depend on which DB engine you are using?

Comment: Mysql Innodb. Added to topic and tags. Thank you:)

Comment: Uh, this is very complicated, depends on isolation levels, transactions, explicit locks. What's the real question behind this?

Comment: @Shadow I think this topic (in this scope) would be interesting to know, if it's knowledge you can share?

Comment: That's more of a blog post than an answer here.

Comment: @Shadow oh yes, plug your blog, by all means! `:-D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some good information here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html

and:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-structure.html

But generally speaking, an Insert locks the row, but it would not prevent a Select (not even a new Insert). A Select query, relying on an index, that is currently being built due to a new Insert, would not "see" the new row until the index is built.

Each Insert operation = insert data into row + change affected indexes. 
The more indexes you have the longer the insert process, the longer it takes before a subsequent SELECT query would find the new row.

If you are writing code, then you can make your Select wait for the Insert to complete.

---

*Adding correction and improvement based on comments below*

I don't mean that the statement takes longer to execute, I mean that if you insert a row at time A, and it takes 5 seconds to complete the operation, then a select query the runs at A+2 seconds wouldn't see the row, a select query running at A+6 seconds would see the row.

To be clearer - the Insert will not delay the Select, unless you configure your DB to have table locks on Insert, but you will not see the Insert in any Select query until the Insert is completed.

Comment: 1. I've read information in those link you've provided and didn't find information relevant to my question or your answer. 2. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding or you're contradicting yourself: first you said that "select query would not see the new row" and instead will(i assume) "see" the previous version of an index. Then you said that "subsequent SELECT query" will take longer because of the insert.

Comment: The main thing I'm trying to understand if INSERT rebuilding the INDEX will in any way delay the SELECT and if yes - then what way is that + proof link if possible.

Comment: 1) I edited my answer - it should have been "the longer it takes before..."
2) The first link above explains how Inserts don't block Selects, because Inserts only have a lock on the row it is inserting. The other link on the physical structure was an aside, as your question was pretty general.
3) No, Insert and rebuilding the Index has no impact on another connection executing a Select statement, unless you reconfigure your DB to apply Table locks on Insert.

Comment: These statements are contradictory: "Insert and rebuilding the Index has no impact on another connection executing a Select statement" and "The more indexes you have the longer the insert process, the longer it takes before a subsequent SELECT query would find the new row.". If select statement takes longer to find row, then index DOES impact select. Or is there something I'm not getting right?

Comment: I don't mean that the statement takes longer to execute, i mean that if you insert a row at time A, and it takes 5 seconds to complete the operation, then a select query the runs at A+2 seconds wouldn't see the row, a select query running at A+6 seconds would see the row.

To be clearer - the Insert will not delay the Select, unless you configure your DB to have table locks on Insert, but you will not see the Insert in any Select query until the Insert is completed.

Comment: Now I get it! Could you please add this last comment to your actual answer, so that I could approve it as the correct one?

Comment: These Comments seem to be mixing the atomicity of index updates with atomicity of a transaction.

Comment: well, if you could explain how exactly are the mixing it all up, we'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I realized only the first part of my question was clearly answered and I found a clear answer for the second part of my question - **What would happen to the second INSERT? Would it wait for index to be fully updated from previous INSERT or not?** - in a [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) provided by the approved answer.

> Prior to inserting the row, a type of gap lock called an insert
>   intention gap lock is set. This lock signals the intent to insert in
>   such a way that multiple transactions inserting into the same index
>   gap need not wait for each other if they are not inserting at the same
>   position within the gap.

This is the sum of it, but in order to deeply understand i suggest reading the whole thing after the quote.

Again, thank you very much for the approved answer.

Answer (score -1):

Inserting a row in a table merely inserts a new entry in each secondary index.  Inserting the data and inserting a new entry in an index are, as it turns out, virtually identical operations -- Both drill down a BTree (data is organized by the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s), a secondary index is organized by the secondary key column(s)).

The `INSERT`, together with any index updates, are atomic.  That is, the entry is added to the index at the same time (*as far as you can tell by any SQL*) as the row being inserted.

Under the covers (in InnoDB), there is a "Change Buffer" that delays actually writing the index updates to disk.  But even a power failure does not violate the 'atomic' nature of the data+index update.

Transaction isolation modes can let you see (or prevent you from seeing) a record before the "transaction" containing the `INSERT`.  But that is a different level of atomicity.  And it has nothing to do with the indexes.

Comment: "A common misconception is that "inserting one row rebuilds the index". It does not. Inserting a row in a table merely inserts a new entry in each secondary index.". Depending on the row that's being inserted it might take longer or faster to insert a row into an index and this is called "updating" an index. I've read up on how the b-tree works yesterday while trying to figure out the answer to my question. And also your answer is missing the whole point of my question.

Comment: I see why you even wrote it, now I've changed "rebuilding" to "updating" in the "updated" part of my question. Although, I wrote "updated" just before and I don't think it matters saying "rebuilding" or "updating", because you have to read the whole question and not just one word.

Comment: OK, I removed "rebuild" from my answer.  The rest of the answer still applies.  The updating of the index(es) is both atomic with the `INSERT` _and_ so fast that there is very little to worry about.